# How to provide public access to jQuery plugin using jquery-boilerplate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, jquery-plugins, jquery-boilerplate

I am trying the [jquery-boilerplate](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/jquery.boilerplate.js) pattern over the one the jQuery team provides in the [learn plugin section](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/) of their site.

I provide public access to default settings as I learned in the [Advanced Plugin Concepts](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/) section. The code below is a simple example of how public access is used:

```
$.fn.hilight = function( options ) {
    var opts = $.extend( {}, $.fn.hilight.defaults, options );

};

$.fn.hilight.defaults = {
    foreground: "red",
    background: "yellow"
};

// Example of usage
$.fn.hilight.defaults.foreground = "blue";

$( ".hilightDiv" ).hilight();

$( "#green" ).hilight({
    foreground: "green"
});
```

#### I was wondering, is it possible to provide public access to the plugin using the [jquery-boilerplate](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/jquery.boilerplate.js)? And if it is possible, how can I do it?

This is the code I am testing:

```
;( function( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    "use strict";

    var pluginName = "boilerplateTest",
        defaults = {
            random: "random text",
            random2: {
                one: 1,
                two: 2
            }
        };

    function Plugin( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;
        this.mainSettings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
    }

    $.extend( Plugin.prototype, {
        init: function() {
            var cfg = this.mainSettings;

            this.printToConsole( cfg );
        },
        printToConsole: function( e ) {
            console.log( e );
        }
    } );

    $.fn[ pluginName ] = function( options ) {
        return this.each( function() {
            if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
                $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName,
                new Plugin( this, options ) )
            }
        } );
    };
} )( jQuery, window, document );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.fn[ pluginName ]` is effectively the same as `$.fn.hilight`, so you can just directly do a replacement.

```
;( function( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    "use strict";

    var pluginName = "boilerplateTest";

    $.fn[ pluginName ] = function( options ) {
        return this.each( function() {
            if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
                $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName,
                new Plugin( this, options ) )
            }
        } );
    };

    $.fn[ pluginName ].defaults = {
            random: "random text",
            random2: {
                one: 1,
                two: 2
            }
        };

    function Plugin( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;
        this.mainSettings = $.extend( {}, $.fn[ pluginName ].defaults, options );
        this._defaults = $.fn[ pluginName ].defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
    }

    $.extend( Plugin.prototype, {
        init: function() {
            var cfg = this.mainSettings;

            this.printToConsole( cfg );
        },
        printToConsole: function( e ) {
            console.log( e );
        }
    } );

} )( jQuery, window, document );
```

See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dma2tbyp/1/).